# onChange function stops after one click, what code do I need to write so that it continues indefinitely? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop, onchange

```js
change = function(event) {
  let new_url;
  if (event.target.value == "views") {
    new_url = "images/desert.jpg";
  } else if (event.target.value == "beaches") {
    new_url = "images/beach-calm.jpg";
  } else if (event.target.value == "party") {
    new_url = "images/plane-wing.jpg";
  }

  let image_two = document.getElementById("image-two");
  if (new_url && image_two.src.indexOf("images/second-main-image.png") != -1) {
    image_two.src = new_url;
  }
}
```

```html
          <select id="select-one" class="suggestion-dropbox" name="likes" onchange="change(event)">
            <option id="default" value="default"> </option>
            <option id="views" value="views">stunning views</option>
            <option id="beaches" value="beaches">glorious white beaches</option>
            <option id="party" value="party">places to party</option>
          </select>
```

I have a dropdown menu and when a different option is clicked I want an image on the page to change with it. I have managed to make it do this however only does it once and stops after that. I've added the code so far below.

Do I need to make it a while loop and if so how would I structure it? Thanks for any help

Comment: please paste code, we do not want to manually type everything out

Comment: You have two definitions of `change()`. Only the last one will be used.

Comment: You should just have one function, and it can use `if/else if` to check `event.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

Your second function definition is replacing the first one, so you only update the image when you select beaches.

You need one function that checks for both options.

It only works one time because you only change the image when it contains `images/second-main-image.png`. After you've selected something from the menu, that's no longer true. You should remove that check.

And if you want to go back to the default when the user selects the default option, add a case for that.

```js
change = function(event) {
  let new_url;
  if (event.target.value == "views") {
    new_url = "images/desert.jpg";
  } else if (event.target.value == "beaches") {
    new_url = "images/beach-calm.jpg";
  } else {
    new_url = ("images/second-main-image.png");
  }

  let image_two = document.getElementById("image-two");
  image_two.src = new_url;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-one" class="suggestion-dropbox" name="likes" onchange="change(event)">
  <option id="default" value="default"> </option>
  <option id="views" value="views">stunning views</option>
  <option id="beaches" value="beaches">glorious white beaches</option>
  <option id="party" value="party">places to party</option>
</select>

<img id="image-two" src="images/second-main-image.png">
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for that, I pasted that code in however it still only lets me click an option once. I cannot change the dropdown after the first go. And it doesn't let me go back to the default value either. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you replace your images with HTML that I can copy and paste I may be able to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate your help

Comment: Put the code in the question so you can format it properly. Use the `[<>]` Stack Snippet tool.

Comment: Is that better? Sorry, I'm a tad new to this

Comment: You should post the original code, so readers can see what my answer was correcting.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work a second time is because it only changes the image when the src is `images/second-main-image.png`. After you choose something from the menu, that's no longer true.

Comment: Right, I understand, how would I change it so that it will change when the source is any image?